# Windows JDK no compiler error - Already tried PATH, installed/reinstalled x64 and x86. What's going on?

Tags: java, windows, maven

I've spent about 10 hours on this already and tried and retried solutions I found on the net, but I'm not finding any new solutions, and getting no where with the ones I've tried. Could you assist?

Background:
I'm new to dev environments like this, so there could be something simple I missed. I'm trying to learn to create Alexa Skills and compile a set of sample files with Maven:

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/deploying-a-sample-skill-to-aws-lambda

And I'm running this through:

```
mvn assembly:assembly -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies package
```

I'm on Windows 7 Pro x64. I installed jdk-8u60-windows-x64.exe.
Using windows CMD (would be happy for suggestions on a better terminal though!)
Not running Eclipse.

`C:` is root, but I installed the JDK to `E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8`...

I setup JAVA HOME - to the root directory - `E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8`...

I setup PATH with `\bin`; added to the front. Note: There was already a path in there for `\oracle\java`, but I tried with and without that with no change.

I setup maven with M2 and M2_Home.

After all that, I still got the compiler not associated issue. So I tried a bunch of stuff:

- Uninstalled everything and reinstalled everything (x64) with "Run as
  Administrator."
- Put all PATH and _HOME values in User and System Settings.
- Uninstalled everything, reinstall everything as Admin, but x86 this
  time.
- Repeat Path and _Home steps with new Program Files(x86) location.
- For every PATH and _HOME I also tried Progra~1, Progra~2 instead of
  "Program Files".

Nothing worked.

I still get the error `no compiler associated.` There is no Javac.exe in my bin after any install either.

And I have a lot less hair now. Any help would be great.

Comment: although I can not bring your hair back here are some hints: download the server jre from oracle, it contains a JDK / javac.exe. Simply unextract that one and set up your PATH / HOME / everything variables. If this still fails get procmon.exe from sysinternals and run it with a _path_ filter on javac.exe. Then you will know where the compile looks for the javac.exe

Comment: Note the JDK contains a jre bin folder. e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin` but make sure you are using (relative to paths for your JDK installation) `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin` There should definitely be a javac.exe binary in there.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: have you checked ? `7z l server-jre-8u60-windows-x64.tar | find /i "javac.exe"` -> `2015-08-04 21:13:20 .....        15936        16384  jdk1.8.0_60\bin\javac.exe`. I often recommend this "hidden jdk" if the installer fails or you need different versions in parallel

Comment: Finally got it working. Nothing new. Reinstall, that's it, but with a difference.
I re-installed the JRE in a different location from the JDK. Probably noobie mistake(?). 

When I first installed the JDK, I didn't have the JRE. The JDK installer also auto-installed the JRE, but first asked me where to put it. This screen doesn't specifically reference JRE apart from JDK. And me, not really understanding the difference between the two, nor the need for another install location, just used the same folder. 

That was probly the issue, because now it's working perfectly. Thank you all.

Comment: @CitizenChan please either create an answer or delete this question

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working. Nothing new. Reinstall, that's it, but with a difference. I re-installed the JRE in a different location from the JDK. Probably noobie mistake(?). When I first installed the JDK, I didn't have the JRE. The JDK installer also auto-installed the JRE, but first asked me where to put it. This screen doesn't specifically reference JRE apart from JDK. And me, not really understanding the difference between the two, nor the need for another install location, just used the same folder. That was probly the issue, because now it's working perfectly. Thank you all.